# Cannot passing value and onChange as props in React-Select

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select, formik

I'm trying to wrap React-Select v2 as my customized component and integrate with formik, I couldn't pass `value` as string props, and `onChange` either.

My Select Component

```
interface Props {
    ...
    selectedValue?: string;
    onChange: ChangeEventHandler;
    ...
}
```

```
const SelectReact: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => {

    return (
        <Select ... value={props.selectedValue} onChange={props.onChange} ... />

    )
};

export default SelectReact;
```

What I want to do with React-Select and Formik,
but now got error message

```
<Formik ... >
            {
                (formProps: FormikProps<TaskFormValues>) => (
                    <form onSubmit={formProps.handleSubmit}>

                        <SelectReact value={formProps.values.value}
                          onChange={formProps.handleChange}
                           ...
                        />
                        <div>
                         //Save Button 
                        </div>
                    </form>
                )}
        </Formik>
```

Any ideas are welcome, thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: What does the error message say?

Answer (score 0):

The [`Formik` GitHub page](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/master/README.md#examples) has examples for the implementation of `react-select` into the form library. You should look there for guidance.

Comment: I checked that example already. react-select set `value` type as `ValueType<OptionType>` , the example using JavaScript which is fine. I'm still quite confused about it, it actually doesn't solve my problem, thanks anyway.

Comment: `react-select` expects `value` to be an object, not a string, that is where I believe your error is. Also, `onChange` prop does not provide an event. The selected option is the first argument in this function. The examples from `Formik` should have made that clear.

Comment: cool, thanks. I figured out the value type, however, still confused about `onChange`.... I will see if I can find out a way to wrap it into my component....